# BACnet segmentation-not-supported on mobile

Tags: bacnet

I'm implementing a bacnet library to read and write some object instances.
But I don't understand, why with a PC and with an application like Yabe if I ask to a common controller to read more than 300 objects, the segmentation is supported, instead with a mobile phone and on the same request to the same controller the segmentation is not supported. 
Both the PC and the smartphone are in the same network on Wifi.
So what is the problem/difference?

Comment: Well, BACnet/IP uses UDP as its communication protocol, we knows that UDP available for many platfroms based on pc, neither for mobile platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing to take with a PC or a mobile phone. Any IP compatible devices mobile phone, desktop, laptop, Arduino chips will work with BACnet.
Your problem is segmentation. You will have to handle the segmented messages coming from the Controller.
Every BACnet controller vendor specifies the MaxApduLength (i.e max length of data to be transferred within one UDP packet). The standard APDU length is 1476 bytes. So a BACnet controller cannot send the data more than the length of APDU specified within it.

Requesting 300 objects from a controller results definitely in a large APDU than the controller's limit. In this case Controller will send you segmented messages each with sequence number. You will have to handle this all segmented messages and combine them in one message then only you will get exact response. This is same with Yabe and other BACnet clients.

I have also written BACnet libraries for our mobile applications in Java and Swift 4.0 and both can read any number of objects from controller with segmentation support added. I have tested these with controllers having more than 400 objects.

Comment: Thank you @Ashwani, that confirm to me that there is a problem with the library that i’m using. I was confused because with wireshark you can see that in this case there is a sort of first-comunication in which: 1) the controller send a message to say that there will be a segmentation 2) the other side respond with an ACK 3) then the message segmented is sent. So i think that the ACK of segmentation from library side is missing and the handle of it is missing as well.

Comment: Yes, this is the only reason. For every segmented message(contains indication that there are more segments) sent by Controller is acknowledged from other side. Once controller receives an acknowledgement for one segment it sends another segment(indicating if more segments are there or no)

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation is used for APDUs (responses) that are too large to fit in one frame on the datalink. If both devices support segmentation, then great. If one of the device does not support segmentation, and the APDU does not fit, then "Segmentation not supported" error is issued. (and you have to then retry a smaller request).